# How to Loop over dictionary and return output of specific values to Numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I am trying to loop over a dictionary, in this case the citi bike data, and pull out the values of the specific keys 'lat' and 'lon', and then put those values in a numpy array. I was able to pull the data from the URL but when trying a for loop I am getting stuck. The dictionary is 'datadict' which I pulled from the URL.

```
import requests
response = requests.get("https://gbfs.citibikenyc.com/gbfs/en/station_information.json")
datadict = response.json()
```

I tried this comprehension first and then tried forming a regular for statement.

```
    import numpy as np
    dict_reduce = {key: datadict[key] for key in datadict.values() & {'lon', 'lat'}} 
    coordinates = np.array(dict_reduce)

    result = list()
    for key in datadict:
        for x in datadict[key]:
            result.append(x['lon'])
```

Dictionary Preview:

```
"""
[{'capacity': 55,
  'eightd_has_key_dispenser': False,
  'eightd_station_services': [],
  'electric_bike_surcharge_waiver': False,
  'external_id': '66db237e-0aca-11e7-82f6-3863bb44ef7c',
  'has_kiosk': True,
  **'lat': 40.76727216,**
  'legacy_id': '72',
  **'lon': -73.99392888,**
  'name': 'W 52 St & 11 Ave',
  'region_id': '71',
  'rental_methods': ['KEY', 'CREDITCARD'],
  'rental_uris': {'android': 'https://bkn.lft.to/lastmile_qr_scan',
   'ios': 'https://bkn.lft.to/lastmile_qr_scan'},
  'short_name': '6926.01',
  'station_id': '72',
  'station_type': 'classic'},
 {'capacity': 33,
  'eightd_has_key_dispenser': False,
  'eightd_station_services': [],
  'electric_bike_surcharge_waiver': False,
  'external_id': '66db269c-0aca-11e7-82f6-3863bb44ef7c',
  'has_kiosk': True,
  'lat': 40.71911552,
  'legacy_id': '79',
  'lon': -74.00666661,
  'name': 'Franklin St & W Broadway',
  'region_id': '71',
  'rental_methods': ['KEY', 'CREDITCARD'],
  'rental_uris': {'android': 'https://bkn.lft.to/lastmile_qr_scan',
   'ios': 'https://bkn.lft.to/lastmile_qr_scan'},
  'short_name': '5430.08',
  'station_id': '79',
  'station_type': 'classic'},
"""
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need.

```
dict_reduce = [{key: d[key] for key in {'lon', 'lat'} } for d in datadict]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to directly pull out the `lat` and `long` values from each element in the list.

From your dictionary preview it looks more like a list of dictionaries rather than a single dictionary and you need to account for that.

```
lat_list = list()
long_list = list()

for elem in datadict:
    lat_list.append(elem['lat'])
    long_list.append(elem['lon'])
```